# Dynamically adding steps to SSO with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, single-page-application, identityserver4

I`m facing some problems when trying to customize one of the quickstarts from identityServer4 [QuickStart 9](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage), basically, I need to create a single sign-on application that will be used by several services, multiple web applications, one electron, and PhoneGap app.

Currently, my flow is a bit more complicated than simply authenticating the user, see below:

User inputs login and password -> system validates this piece of data and presents the user with a selection of possible sub-applications to select -> the user selects one of the sub-applications -> the system now requests the user to select a possible environment for this application (staging/production can be customized)

I want to do this flow on the authentication layer because otherwise, I would have to replicate all these steps on all the apps, and off-course I want the authentication to have separate development lifecycle.

Currently, I'm trying to make 3 modifications to achieve this:

1. PersistentGrantStore -> save this steps to a custom table using the
   grant key as a reference. (something like
   Key/application/environment)
2. IProfileService -> add custom claims that represent this steps
       **(stuck here)**, and are temporary, they only have meaning for this token and subsequent refreshes.
3. authenticationHandler -> validate if the user went through all the
       steps

I will also need to make a modification to the token endpoint to accept these 2 parameters via custom header due to my spa`s apps

**my question boils down to**: is there a better way to this? am I overcomplicating this?

sorry if this question is too basic, but I`m not used to doing this type of auth.

Comment: Not really sure I understand your question, but all that thing about applications and environment is not necessary. Every of your application gets **its own** client entry in your Identity Server. i.e. App A Production and App A Staging, App B Production, App B staging. These you configure within identity, tell it which claims to add/return to the necessary endpoints/token types.

Comment: To me it sounds like you are trying to run multiple applications with the same client id. This is not in the sense of OpenID. For OpenID you are supposed to have one client entry per application and environment, this wake revocations can work more detailed (blocking a specific client) and its for the security too. The client id and client secret are confidential (server apps) and you can use different flows for different application (auth code for server, implicit for mobile apps and browser apps etc)

Comment: Actually, I was not thinking on using the same clientId for all the applications, what I meant by "multiple applications with multiple clients" is that every application will be a multi-tenant application and each tenant can connect to multiple environments (databases) - basicaly Token A was generated for application B with environment C these should became claims of this token alone.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, following way might be helpful.

Create a temp cookie and display select page after user loggedin:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var loginResult = .service.Check(model.Username, model.Password);
        if (loginResult.IsSucceed)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync("TempCookies", loginResult.Principal);
            var selectViewModel = new SelectViewModel();
            model.ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl;
            return View("SelectUserAndEnvironment", selectViewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "****.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Add claims you want and sign in for `IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme`

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "TempCookies")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SelectUserAndEnvironment(SelectModel model)
{
    // add claims from select input
    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim(<Type>, <Value>));
    var p = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(auth.Principal?.Identity, claims));
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("TempCookies");
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme, p);
    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
}
```

And use claims in `ProfileService`

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    // you can get claims added in login action by using context.Subject.Claims
    // other stuff
    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Finally add authentication scheme in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("TempCookies", options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 300);
            })
```

If you want to use external login, change above code appropriately.